# Using streams/ functional programming for multiple arrays in Java 8

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I have 2 arrays, `y` & `z`
I want to return an integer array where `result[i] = y[i] - z[i]`

Here's the code:

```
static int[] join(int[] y, int[] z) {
    int[] result = new int[Math.min(y.length, z.length)];
    for(int i = 0; i < result.length; ++i) {
        result[i] = y[i] - z[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

However I want to do the same thing using Java's 8 functional programming techniques such as streams. However all the stream functions I'm aware of only work for one list at a time.

How can I do this?

**Edit**
Also how can I do the same thing that I mentioned but instead I want to return a boolean array where: `result[i] = y[i] == 5 || z[i] == 10`

Comment: Usually parallel lists/arrays smell. Why don't you have an array like `YZ[]` (or better `List<YZ>`) of something like `class YZ {int y, z;}`? And why would you need the resulting `int[]` or `boolean[]` array? How do you plan to use it further? Usually having parallel arrays is ok only in low-level math libraries (like matrix processing) where switching to streams seems unnecessary...

Answer (score 5):

You can use `IntStream` to *simulate* iteration with a counter variable:

```
static int[] join(int[] y, int[] z) {
    int min = Math.min(y.length, z.length);
    return IntStream.range(0, min).map(i -> y[i] - z[i]).toArray();
}
```

Comment: How about if i wanted to return a boolean array instead (see edited question). Good solution so far!

Comment: @YahyaUddin For a `boolean[]` result, the `for` loop approach is preferable, as there is no `BoolStream` and there is as far as I know no way to easily convert a `Stream<Boolean>` to a `boolean[]`.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> static int[] join(int[] y, int[] z) {
>     int[] result = new int[Math.min(y.length, z.length)];
>     for(int i = 0; i < result.length; ++i) {
>         result[i] = y[i] - z[i];
>     }
>     return result;
> }
> ```

A shorthand way to do this is to replace the for-loop with the following:

```
    Arrays.setAll(result, i -> y[i] - z[i]);
```

Unfortunately there's no way to do this if the result is a `boolean[]`, since the primitive specializations for `Arrays.setAll` are provided only for the usual `int`, `long`, and `double`.

But there's no magic here; `Arrays.setAll` just uses `IntStream.range()` to implement an aggregate operation over all the array indexes. Thus:

```
static boolean[] join(int[] y, int[] z) {
    boolean[] result = new boolean[Math.min(y.length, z.length)];
    IntStream.range(0, result.length)
             .forEach(i -> result[i] = y[i] == 5 || z[i] == 10);
    return result;
}
```